# Embed javascript code in spidermonkey in multithreaded application

Tags: javascript, c++, multithreading, spidermonkey

I want to develop mutithreaded C++ code to embed javascript in it using spidermonkey, so it was supposed that when I was building spidermonkey source code, I should build it as thread safety "-DJS_THREADSAFE" OR if I didn't do that I can use it and get the benefit of multithread code and when compiling my application I set the option of building the application as thread safety "-DJS_THREADSAFE" and don't need to rebuild the source code of spidermonkey ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Support for JS_THREADSAFE was recently removed, and threadsafe builds are now enabled by default.”
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Build_Documentation#Building_your_application